# How to incorporate more complex logic into asyncio futures list comprehension

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio

I have written a function for downloading activity IDs from Strava's public API.

The function iterates the API pages, collects the IDs and stops after it has collected IDs from the page it has identified as the last one:

```
 import requests

 def get_activity_ids(): 
            """Returns a list of activity ids for the token owner"""            
            ids = []
            params = {
                'page': 1,
                'per_page':200, 
                'access_token':'1111111',
            } 
            while True:              
                r = requests.get('https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities', params).json()
                if len(r) == 0:
                    break
                else:
                    ids += [activity['id'] for activity in r]
                    if len(r) < 200: # if last page
                        break
                print('PAGE: {}, response length: {}'.format(params['page'], len(r)))
                params['page'] += 1
            return ids
```

I now want to turn this function into an asynchronous one.
So far I got this:

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import requests

def get_ids():
    ids = []
    async def main():
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            futures = [
                loop.run_in_executor(
                    executor,
                    requests.get,
                    'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?page={page}&per_page=200&access_token=111111111'.format(page=page)
                )
                for page in range(1,4)
            ]
            for response in await asyncio.gather(*futures):
                for activity in response.json():
                    ids.append(activity['id'])
                pass
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    return ids
```

But I don't know know how to incorporate the identification of last page logic from previous function (the `while True` block) into this one.

So I would need to somehow replace the `for i in range(1,4)` with such logic.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to parallelize operations that cannot be run in parallel. Each request needs to wait for the previous request to finish before you know whether the next request should even happen. This is inherently sequential.

If you're okay with requesting nonexistent pages, you could probably submit a limited number of requests in parallel, making more requests as previous requests finish, and stopping once you find you've hit the end. This would not be as simple as a list comprehension and a `gather`, though.

Comment: Or you need to use some other means to get the page number of the last page so that you can replace the range with one those last index is the last actual page.